# azure active directory graph REST api call through SP.WebRequestInfo on SharePoint Online

Tags: api, rest, azure, active-directory, sharepoint-online

Trying to make a REST call through SharePoint's SP.WebRequestInfo.

I'm getting the error "The remote server returned the following error while establishing a connection - 'Unauthorized'." trying to call https://graph.windows.net/[Client]/users?api-version=2013-11-0.

I've successfully retrieved a access token.

Can you help me out why i'm getting this error?

Here is the code i'm using:

```
        var url = "https://graph.windows.net/xxx/users/?api-version=2013-11-08";

        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
        request.set_url(url);
        request.set_method("GET");
        request.set_headers({
            "Authorization": token.token_type + " " + token.access_token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        });

        var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

        context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);

        function successHandler() {
            if (response.get_statusCode() == 200) {
                var responseBody = JSON.parse(response.get_body());
                deferred.resolve(responseBody);
            } else {

                var httpCode = response.get_statusCode();
                var httpText = response.get_body();
                deferred.reject(httpCode + ": " + httpText);
            }
        }
```

The code for retrieving the token is:

```
    this.getToken = function (clientId, clientSecret) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var resource = "https://graph.windows.net";
        var formData = "grant_type=client_credentials&resource=" + encodeURIComponent(resource)      + "&client_id=" + encodeURIComponent(clientId) + "&client_secret=" + encodeURIComponent(clientSecret);

        var url = "https://login.windows.net/xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0";

        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var request = new SP.WebRequestInfo();
        request.set_url(url);
        request.set_method("POST");
        request.set_body(formData);

        var response = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);

        context.executeQueryAsync(successHandler, errorHandler);

        function successHandler() {
            if (response.get_statusCode() == 200) {
            var token = JSON.parse(response.get_body());
            deferred.resolve(token);
        } else {
            var httpCode = response.get_statusCode();
            var httpText = response.get_body();
            deferred.reject(httpCode + ": " + httpText);
        }
    }

    function errorHandler() {
        deferred.reject(response.get_body());
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  };
```

Comment: Azure AD Graph API accepts access tokens with audience of 'https://graph.windows.net/'. Please show me the code that acquires the token.

Comment: @DushyantGill I have updated the question wth the code that acquires the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erik, something is strange here - you are using the client credential flow from a JavaScript client - this reveals the secret issued to the client app to the user of the JS app.

The client credential flow also requires the directory admin to grant directory read permission to the client application - not sure if this was already configured - nevertheless it must only be used with a confidential client, not a public client like a JS app.

Azure AD does not yet implement the implicit_grant oauth flow using which a JS client app can acquire an access token on behalf of the user over redirect binding (in the fragment). This is a hugh-pro requirement that we're working on - stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks Dushyant, looking forward to the new features. Is there any plans on supporting JSONP in the API?

Comment: Hi Dushyant, we are working on a AngularJS based client app and also looking for a method to acquire an access token to query Azure Graph API.  Hopefully this will be available soon! Thank you!